# Error Uncaught Error== Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on string in /*Source*/

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php code where a student can view his/her grades through logging in with his code and full name. But I have a little problem in displaying the selected data from the sql database

I tried doing the sql query on the **phpmyadmin** of **xampp**. and correcting some potential errors

```
$view = "SELECT a.code,a.name,b.schedule,c.code,c.name,c.description from student as a, subjectgroup as b,subject as c,enrolledsubject as d where a.id=d.studentID AND d.subjectGroupID = b.id and b.subjectID = c.id";
        while ($data=$view ->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>".$data["a.code"];
        }
```

this is a part where I tried to show the first data of the array

Expected result should have been  the code, then the name, then another...

Comment: Please read [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php) first. It seems you haven't started with it yet.

Comment: @DrakulaPredator I already know the **sql part**, the problem is how to display it with multiple selection. Before it was fine with singe table but the error appeared with **more-than one table**

Comment: Your code reflects you are missing basics and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and please read the documentations first

```
$view = "SELECT a.code a_code,a.name a_name,b.schedule,c.code as c_code,c.name as c_name,c.description from student as a, subjectgroup as b,subject as c,enrolledsubject as d where a.id=d.studentID AND d.subjectGroupID = b.id and b.subjectID = c.id";
$data=mysqli_query($your_db_connection,$view);   
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
   echo "<tr><td>".$row['a_code']."</td><td>".$row['a_name']."</td><td>".$row['c_code']."</td><td>".$row['c_name']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry for being arrogant. There's some error on the code I submitted.